# Restoration impossible on my Asus n73s

Tags: windows-7, boot

My Asus n73s will not start. The screen turns blue, restarts and turns black with just a blinking cursor.

It's impossible to restore with the CD. Safe Mode stops at "loading windows \ system32 \ drivers \ disk.sys" then it goes back to the blue screen and then restarts

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Bien venue à SuperUser. S'il vous plaît écris ton question en anglais; pas toutes les utilisateurs de ce web-site comprend la langue française et peut pas t'aider.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably hardware error. Either RAM or motherboard, maybe HDD. I'd recommend giving a go to [Hiren Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) or any other diagnostic tool or toolset you can boot from CD and test your HW. If it finds nothing after a heavy duty HW test, delete HDD partitions, format it, then install a new copy of the OS. But based on your description, I'm quite confident it's HW issue.

Answer (score -1):

Could be problem with your system or drivers

First try to repair your system by your Win 7 CD .. choose repair system

Comment: the QA clearly states it is impossible to recover via CD.

Comment: No, Nadia said -- It's impossible to restore with the CD -- because in that condition we still can do something by win7 CD boot .. at least we save our archive, files or elses ..

Comment: that's not a repair then. its a backup.

Comment: Hey .. backup from what ? .. Like I said -- repair --. Just try to fix the crash that might be solved by repair system ..

Comment: read the question better please.